# Jitsi always offline on Gmail account

Tags: instant-messaging

I installed Jitsi messenger and added Gmail account. However, it simply cannot go online. I see it tried to go online and after 1/2s it's reverted back to offline.

Is Google blocking this app maybe? What can I do to solve this?